# htaccss RewriteRule - Remove .html and query from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some "dirty" urls in Google cache and index which keep popping up.

I've made efforts to remove them, but in the meanwhile I would like to create a redirect using a htaccess RewriteRule.

I've had partial success, but not complete.

Original URL
http://www.domain.net/folder/132-article-title**.html?tmpl=component&type=raw**

Rewrite URL
http://www.domain.net/folder/132-article-title

So far I've got

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html(.*) http://www\.domain\.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But all it's doing is removing **.html** from the URL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove the query string entirely. It gets automatically appended with `[R]` redirect unless you have something in the rewrite to replace it.  To remove it completely, append a `?`:

```
# Add a ? to replace the whole query string with an empty string
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www\.domain\.net/$1? [L,R=301]
```

Note that I have added a `$` after `.html` to indicate the string ends there.  The query string is *not* matched in the left side of a `RewriteRule` so you don't need a `(.*)` there.

Comment: Thank you Michael - The rule worked perfectly and the explanation helped a lot!